# Extracting Color Features from an Image

Tags: image, image-processing, feature-extraction

I would like to extract Color and Texture features from Training images for the purpose of automatic annotation . On Googling I found algorithms some algorithms.

Can somebody guide me to the specific tools or existing code for this task preferably in C++.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) is a large computer vision library which has a C++ interface. It provides functions to calculate a large number of colour and texture features. Perhaps you should look at some of the tutorials to learn what it can do: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html

Good luck!